# How to create a new public AMI for windows server 2016 with a random password?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a custom AMI from EC2 windows server 2016. the new EC2 created using the custom AMI is not generating password? any idea how to fix?

Comment: Can you provide some more details on how you created your AMI? Have you read up on how to use EC2Launch, which is the PowerShell modules that AWS uses to do post-deployment configurations, including generating random passwords?

Comment: Actually it solved the issue by running EC2 Launch Setting, then ticked Random (Retrieve from console) and also ticked Run EC2Launch on every boot.